# How to spell these words in Chinese alphabets?

Tags: characters, spelling, calligraphy

since there is a wide range of **letters** in Chinese  language , I need your **best offers** on **spelling (pronounce)** these words by use of only **Chinese  Characters** in its **most accurate** form ?

the spelling in English is like this :

> fereydoon shekofte

and you can listen to [the original voice here](http://vocaroo.com/i/s1H2nZQkYF4X)

*I need these characters for calligraphy too!*

Comment: 1. Voting to close as "off-topic -- translation request". 2. The Chinese writing system is not an alphabet, and transliterating words or names into Chinese is not a mechanical process.

Comment: Are you just looking for your "Chinese Name"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do we choose the correct characters for a westerner name?](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/242/how-do-we-choose-the-correct-characters-for-a-westerner-name)

Comment: Vote against closing. 1. It's not a random translation request like "this is a pen". It's something that tests one's cultural knowledge and translation skills. You don't provide an answer without checking some references. I for one have no idea how to translate Persian or Arabic names. 2. Such questions would be surely beyond the OP's abilities, or even most native speaker's abilities. It's understandable that the OP didn't show his effort. 3. The question is interesting, isn't it?

Comment: Nah I reckon it should be closed. This Q will not provide any benefit to anybody else coming to chinese.SE, so the request could be made in Chat.

Comment: No benefit to anyone else? I can imagine myself translating a book and stumbling upon such a name, then I googled and hit the answer below -- convenient, no?

Comment: Except the answer to this question won't be definitive; they will be subjective. Translating the name might not be phonetical, it might be based on the meaning. Or there might be slight differences in the chosen characters. The request itself is open-ended; people can come up with lots of things. So in your imagination's book, it may be written one way, but all the answers here are written another.

Comment: did you attention to my note on **calligraphy ?** i don't know were is the best place for asking such questions from professionals ! as you recognized this is the vocal transformation from one language to another , suppose i want to travel china then **how should i write my name for Chinese men** ? i doomed to write it in Latin ?

Comment: @FereydoonShekofte Sorry, but if you don't speak any Chinese at all, why bother translating your name into Chinese? If you ever go to China, you won't have any occasion to use it anyway, since you will be communicating in English. I also think you don't understand what calligraphy is, you just want to show off to your friends, or worse, you want to ink it onto you, but Chinese language was not invented for supposedly 'fashionable' tattoos.  This site is not a free translation service, it's intended for people learning Chinese, so your question is off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

弗里顿

> Fereydoon
>
> From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia
>
> Fereydoon, Fereydoun or Ferydoon (Persian: فریدون) may refer to:

> Ferydoon Zandi_百度百科
>
> 姓名：**弗里顿**·赞迪

Comment: the second one, maybe: 希卡斯塔

Answer (score 1):

I'm Chinese , I think it make no sense to spell this voice in Chinese Characters. And even if you give the spelling , I don't think I can understand what it is.

Beside, don't use Chinese Characters to spell any other language's voice unless there is a usage of oral speaking in Chinese.Just write what it is and explain it in Chinese in `()`. Like this:

> Blockquote（这个英语单词表示引用的意思）

And are you looking for Chinese Name?